# How to find out which imported modules change global numpy.random seed

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

In a large project, I used several random variate generators (i.e. there are method calls to create random variables other than 0,1 uniform). I used both scipy.stats and numpy methods and it requires months of work to change them. I found out that some packages resets np.random seed. Is there a way to detect calls to np.random.seed() method? Or can I learn when it is called by modules like pandas, scipy.stats etc. from somewhere and be sure that it won't be called after I set the seed?

Comment: You may need to explain how this causing problems.  Are you setting the seed yourself (for testing purposes)?  Newer numpy versions let you create your own `rng`, and not depend on the stock one and its seed.  This article may help, https://albertcthomas.github.io/good-practices-random-number-generators/

Comment: I need to reproduce all random numbers in the project. If any package changes the seed in the middle of the code, then results cannot be reproduced. And yes I am setting the seed via np.random.seed(.). Unfortunately it is too late to use rng and also as far as i know I cannot use scipy.stats random variate generators with rng